# What is the /packages/$sdk/ folder inside a Google Dart build for?

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart2js, dartium

After building a Google Dart web app in Dart Editor (the `Pub Build (Generates JS)` option) the folder layout is like [this](http://i.gyazo.com/71fb486e7f00766161c16b4ac7dbcd2c.png).  My app imports both `dart:html` and `dart:async` but It seems I can upload everything but the `$sdk` folder to my server and the app will run fine in both Dartium and in other browsers.  Is there some reason I need to upload the `$sdk` folder, and what is it for?  Tried googling but I see no answer, thanks in advance!

Edit: [Here's a working example of my project from DartEditor 1.5.8](http://chrs.ws/dart/hexclock/) and below is the code for it.

hexclock.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
DateTime theTime;
String theHour, theMinute, theSecond;
Timer theTimer;
void main() {
  theTimer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), getTime);
}

void updateColours(){
  String bgcol = "#" + theHour + theMinute + theSecond;
  querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = bgcol;
}

void printTime() {
  querySelector("#hour").text = theHour;
  querySelector("#minute").text = theMinute;
  querySelector("#second").text = theSecond;
}

void getTimeInit(){
  theTime = new DateTime.now();
  theHour = "${checkZero(theTime.hour)}";
  theMinute = "${checkZero(theTime.minute)}";
  theSecond = "${checkZero(theTime.second)}";
  printTime();
  updateColours();
}

void getTime(Timer t){
  theTime = new DateTime.now();
  theHour = "${checkZero(theTime.hour)}";
  theMinute = "${checkZero(theTime.minute)}";
  theSecond = "${checkZero(theTime.second)}";
  querySelector("#title").style.opacity = "0";
  querySelector("#clock").style.opacity = "1";
  printTime();
  updateColours();
}

String checkZero(int anInt){
  if (anInt < 10)
    return "0${anInt}";
  else
    return "${anInt}";
}
```

hexclock.html:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>HexClock</title>
    <script async type="application/dart" src="hexclock.dart"></script>
    <script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hexclock.css">
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="title" class="centre">hexclock</div>
    <div id="clock" class="centre">#<span id="hour">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span id="minute">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span id="second">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

pubspec.yaml:

```dart
name: HexClock
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  browser: any
```

Comment: I don't have this folder. What Dart version are you using?

Comment: I have Dart Editor 1.5.8

Answer (score 2):

In the [pub source code](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/barback/asset_environment.dart?spec=svn37511&r=37511) I found this:

```dart
  // "$sdk" is a pseudo-package that allows the dart2js transformer to find
  // the Dart core libraries without hitting the file system directly. This
  // ensures they work with source maps.
  var libPath = path.join(sdk.rootDirectory, "lib");
  var sdkSources = listDir(libPath, recursive: true)
      .where((file) => path.extension(file) == ".dart")
      .map((file) {
    var idPath = path.join("lib",
        path.relative(file, from: sdk.rootDirectory));
    return new AssetId('\$sdk', path.toUri(idPath).toString());
  });
```

I don't know if this matches exactly what you're seeing, but my guess is that it's related. This would in theory allow client-side debugging even through SDK functions, which could be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the entire build folder is intended to be deployed.
There are some redundant files like the `*.dart.pecompiled.js` which are only necessary for CSP environments (Chrome App for example).
I think there was a recent change so that these files are not generated anymore.

There might be other things redundant too but I haven't seen any information about it yet.

You could try with a Dart 1.6 release (stable should be out) and check if this was dropped or if there has to be another explanation.
I use always bleeding_edge which is currently 1.7+.

Another explanation is that this is only created when you build in `debug` mode.
DartEditor does this by default.

Try `pub build` from the command line to see if it is still generated.

Comment: Okay, I see.  I've updated to 1.6 and now when I run `build` from Dart Editor the `/$sdk/` folder in `/packages/` still appears but the `/browser/` folder does not (and the built app does not work!).  When I run `pub build` from the command line the `/packages/` folder does not appear at all. Browser IS in the dependencies file so I have no idea what's happening here.

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? If you want deploy you need to build on the command line. `pub build --mode=debug` like DartEditor calls it skips tree-shaking and minification. This is just for debugging purposes. For deployment you need to run `pub build --mode=release` (`--mode=release` is default on the command line)

Comment: Sorry, I'm brand new to this!   I only just set up the command line for the last comment.  By does not work I mean that the folder `/browser/` containing `dart.js` and `interop.js` is not generated, neither in DartEditor nor command line, and these are needed for the app to run.

Comment: You said it is a simple example. Can you post the code (`index.html`, `index.dart`, `pubspec.yaml`) so we can have a look.

Comment: Sure thing, it's my first Dart project.  Updated the first post.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for (browser directory) was just inlined to the `*.html` or `*.dart` files. Have you tried to open the entry page in a browser? I haven't investigated the build output a lot but usually if it runs when built from DartEditor it will just run when build from command line as well (as long as you don't use reflection/mirrors ;-) )

Comment: I've had a look and nope!  If I open the built file in the browser I get this `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Users/CN/Documents/Website/ws%20domain/dart/hexclock/packages/browser/dart.js`, but it works in Dart Editor.  I've also tried creating new projects and I've even gone back to Dart Editor 1.5.8 and it doesn't work there anymore, lol.  I can manually insert the `/browser/` folder every time but it SHOULD work.  Very weird.

Comment: Do you have the `browser` package in your `pubspec.yaml` dependencies?
Maybe this was a transitive dependency earlier and isn't anymore. What you also can try is to launch Chrome with the argument `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: Ohhhh, when I Run as Javascript from Dart I get the same error.

Comment: I think I have it set correctly, see my original post.  If I manually copy in the `/browser/` folder from the VERY FIRST project then it works without trouble.  I'm not sure we're gonna solve this, but thank you very much for your time, you've been a big help!

Comment: Fixed the problem! Amusingly I followed your advice on another website and that solved it, lol. [See here](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/6QEYk45zPfA).

Comment: Great! This should never be necessary, but in fact it is. Thanks for the feedback.